# Inline formset strange behaviour in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using Inline formset with these two models:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    STATE_CODES = (
                   ('CA', 'California'),
                   ('AL', 'Alaska'),
                   ('FL', 'Florida')
                   )   

    street1 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    street2 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE_CODES, default='California')
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)  


class Friend(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    email = models.EmailField()

form = inlineformset_factory(Address, Friend)
```

When I call `{{form}}` in template it shows `name, address and email` thrice but nothing related to address. What's wrong?

Template code:

```
<form action="." method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="add_address">Submit</button>
        <a href="/xcard/address_book/" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Cancel</a>
    </form>
```

Comment: show your template code

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass "extra" into inlineformset

```
inlineformset_factory(Address, Friend, extra=MAX_ADDRESS)
```

Extra can be any number as per your requirement.
I will suggest you to follow below process to use Inline formset.

```
#models.py
class Address(models.Model):
    STATE_CODES = (
                   ('CA', 'California'),
                   ('AL', 'Alaska'),
                   ('FL', 'Florida')
                   )   

    street1 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    street2 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE_CODES, default='California')
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)  


class Friend(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    email = models.EmailField()

#forms.py 
from django import forms
from .models import Address, Friend
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

MAX_ADDRESS = 1   #updated
AddressFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Address, Friend, extra=MAX_ADDRESS)   #updated

class UserSubmittedAddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address

-------------------------------------------
view.py
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from .models import *
from .forms import UserSubmittedAddressForm, AddressFormSet

def submit_recipe(request):
    if request.POST:
        #processing
    else:
        form = UserSubmittedAddressForm()
        address_formSet = AddressFormSet(instance=Address())
    # render response

#template code
      {{ form.as_table }}
      {{ address_formset.as_table }}
```

Please let me know if any issue .

Comment: It works but address_formset gives the same problem --> display name, email, address thrice.

Comment: What's the use of `inlineformset` if we use two forms. Because instead of these hassle, I can just do:
{{ address_form }}
{{ friend_form }}

Comment: see updated answer  . by default it will always show 3 .. you need to ovveride that with extra

Comment: Also, answer by query please.

Comment: Is that -1 from you, mate?

Comment: Thanks bruh. Appreciate it!